# Android: Buttons don't show output text in emulator when clicked

Tags: java, android, button, textview

**UPDATE:** I've changed the activity code to my best working set. My current problem is that when a button is clicked, the App force closes in the emulator. My Logcat says the issue is at line 38, the switch statement where updateDate() is called and at line 64 which sets the text for the Present Date.

I've created an app that has two buttons that show you the present date and time, when opened in the Android Emulator and clicked there is no text shown below the buttons as it should be. I'm using TextView below the buttons to display the output. Here's the code from my main.xml and activity respectively.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dayOf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonDay"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonTime" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/output"
        android:textSize="72dip"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
package omaxwell.CS211D.TimeAndDate;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.widget.TextView;
/*
 * This is the activity for my Android App that gives you the date and time 
 */
//*******************TimeAndDateActivity*******************
public class TimeAndDateActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button dayOf;
    Button clock;
    @Override
    //*******************onCreate*******************
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        clock = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.clock);   //Time Button
        clock.setOnClickListener(this);

        dayOf = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.dayOf);   //Date Button
        dayOf.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
        //*******************onClick*******************
        public void onClick(View v) //Called when one of the buttons above is clicked
        {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.clock:
                    updateTime();
                    break;
                case R.id.dayOf:
                    updateDate();
                    break;
            }

        }
            //*******************updateTime*******************
            private void updateTime()
            {
                Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
                d.getTime();

                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.output);
                tv.setText(d.getTime().toString());
            }
            //*******************updateDay*******************
            private void updateDate()
            {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                String date = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" +String.valueOf(year);

                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.output);
                tv.setText(date);
            }


}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: kept in try/catch find the exception.. try{tv.setText(date);} catch(){} and then tell..

Answer (score 0):

After creating textView you add it too.. so

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(date);
```

get content View and say,

```
contentLayout.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're creating a new Textview in updateDate() but you're not doing anything with it. Instead, just update your existing Textview:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
txt.setText(date);
```

Comment: Just tried this and ran with emulator, still no output :( could it be a connectivity issue on how the java calendar package that get the time and date? I'm not familiar with how it works.

Comment: Above suggestion is a good first step. However, you'll also need to remove the `setContentView(R.id.info);` calls in `updateTime()` and `updateDate()`. With those you're basically changing what's shown on the screen to a TextView that you're not doing anything with - hence, nothing shows/updates.

Answer (score 0):

I think u didn't set OnClickListener to button

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
        {
           super.onCreate(b);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           clock = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.clock);   //Time Button
           dayOf = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.dayOf);   //Date Button
           clock.setOnClickListener(this);
           dayOf.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
package omaxwell.CS211D.TimeAndDate;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.widget.TextView;
/*
 * This is the activity for my Android App that gives you the date and time 
 */
//*******************TimeAndDateActivity*******************
public class TimeAndDateActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button dayOf;
    Button clock;
    TextView info;

    @Override
    //*******************onCreate*******************
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.main); // set content view firstly


        clock = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.clock);   //Time Button
        dayOf = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.dayOf);   //Date Button
        // set OnClickListener, you can also use the "android:click" attribute in the XML
        clock.setOnClickListener(this);
        dayOf.setOnClickListener(this);

        info = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.info);   //TextView
    }

        //*******************onClick*******************
        public void onClick(View v) //Called when one of the buttons above is clicked
        {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.clock:
                    updateTime();
                    break;  // don't forget break ! Otherwise, updateDate() will be execute

                case R.id.dayOf:
                    updateDate();
                    break;
            }

        }

            //*******************updateTime*******************
            private void updateTime()
            {
                Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
                d.getTime();

                // just update info
                info.setText(d.getTime().toString());

                // Following is wrong!
                //TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                //tv.setText(d.getTime().toString());
                //  setContentView(R.id.info);
            }

            //*******************updateDay*******************
            private void updateDate()
            {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                String date = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" +String.valueOf(year);

                // just update info
                info.setText(d.getTime().toString());

                // Following is wrong!
                //TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                //tv.setText(date);
                // setContentView(R.id.info);
            }
}
```